# How to display the latest 4 news?

Tags: php

I have a news script. This script works like the following:

1. I enter the news details from a form
2. The news is inserted into the database
3. The news is displayed to the visitor

I need to display the latest 4 news only, not all news entries. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Make your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 4
```

where `news_id` is the primary key of your news table.

Comment: ...Assuming MYSQL is used for the database

Comment: @gt: Yeah that is pretty much assumed there :)